# Using Tab key in WSL Ubuntu (Linux Journey)

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, input

I'm trying to follow the Linux journey tutorial in the text-fu section on WSL2 running Ubuntu.

I can't use my Tab key to insert a text tab in the terminal. It just rings the error bell when I press it.

[image: picture of Linux journey]

Comment: So does your `Tab` key trigger the error bell no matter what, or only after you press `Ctrl`+`v`?

Comment: It triggers when i press it in isolation. but when i press ctrl+TAB it brings up a small window for changing between WSL tabs itself.
ctrl-v+tab just results in the clipboard pasting for as long as i hold it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that you are using [`Windows Terminal`](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/windows-terminal/9N0DX20HK701)

It has own actions for `Ctrl+V` and `Ctrl+Tab` shortcuts. You have to disable it to be able use terminal internal actions:

- Open `Settings` tab
- Select `Actions` menu
- Change (or remove) `Paste text` shortcut (for example it will be `Shift+Ctrl+V` for default gnome terminal)
- Change (or remove) `Next tab` shortcut
- Extra recommendation: Change (or remove) `Copy` shortcut (for example it will be `Shift+Ctrl+C` for default gnome terminal), because `Ctrl+C` is also using inside terminal (for example it shows number of current line in `nano` editor)

After you remove Windows shortcuts bash shortcuts automatically become active

<sub>By the way, that is not Ubuntu problem</sub>